# What happens to TCP connection when a computer switches to sleep mode?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, tcp, power-management

I want to know what happens to a TCP connection  when a computer goes to sleep.

Is there any differences between Linux and Windows in aspect of realization of TCP and handling the sleep mode?

So, the question is: *is the connection terminating on sleep mode? If not - what happens?*

Comment: This seems to fit better on serverfault or superuser

Comment: Even if the session remained open, if the other end sends data then obviously they won't get an acknowledgement, they will decide their partner is unresponsive and will unilaterally close the connection. So this is kind of a self-fulfilling prophecy no matter what.

Comment: From my experience - connection remains open and is possibly closed due timeout... have seen it zillion times with SSH session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The networking session terminates when computer goes into sleep mode, due to the fact the networking interface(s) will also shut down, hence no transmission to transmit or receive. TCP is reliable connection and expects other party to respond to handshake process, ACK and other request and sleeping node won't be able to do that.

Comment: There is no such thing as a TCP session. There is a TCP *connection*, and it doesn't specifically terminate when the computer sleeps: it is terminated by the resulting errors.

Comment: I did not say "TCP Session", I said "networking session". Even if I said session, there is a session between two ends, and TCP relies on it to determine whether to start the initiation, end connection, check ACK sequence and so on. Have a look at TCP header and audit simple transmission using Wireshark. There is an assumption about two nodes transmitting data via TCP.